# REST & MEAN Stack: Filling a Form with saved data

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, mean-stack

I´ve got a REST API and a MEAN Application. Users can log in to my app, with their email adress and then write a project to the database, with an html form.
**What I want achieve is**: that when a user has written a project to the database, the html form should be filled with the data out of my database. The wanted array should by identified by the users email adress.

So here we´ve got my html form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="author">Author</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" id="email" value="<%= user.local.email %>" readonly ng-value="email">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Projektname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-value="name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Beschreibung</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" ng-value="description">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="tags">Tags</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tags" ng-value="tags">
</div>
```

My Mongoose Schema:

```
var mongoose    = require ('mongoose');

var projectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        author      : String,
        name        : String,
        description : String,
        tags        : String,
        media       : {data: Buffer, contentType: String},
        updated_at  : {type: Date, default: Date.now },
        active      : Boolean
});
```

My Routes:

```
    //GET /projects/:id
    app.get('/projects_view/:id', function (req, res, next) {
        Project.findById(req.params.id, function (err, project) {
            if (err) return next (err);
            res.json(project);
        });
    });

    //PUT /projects/:id
    app.put('/projects_view/:id', function (req, res, next) {
        Project.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
            if (err) return next (err);
            res.json(post);
        });
    });
```

**My approach to a solution:**

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller("formController", ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', function($scope, $http, $filter){
        $http.get('/projects_view/').
        then(function(res){
            var allProjects = res.data;
            var singleProject = $filter('filter')(allProjects, function(d){
                return d.author === email;
                });
            };
        });
    }]);
</script>
```

I was trying it with `$find` but it doesnt seem to work for me.
Does anybody got an idea how i can achieve this?

Kind regards from Germany,
David

Comment: To be more specific: My goal is to make mongoose query, to find my projects written by a specific email-address. The adress has to be passed from the view, to the router. My response should be thrown out in the html form of the view, if there was a database entry for that email address

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to do this.

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Project= mongoose.model('Project');
app.post('/projects_view', function(req, res, next) {
  var project_post = new Project(req.body);
  Project.findOne({ email:project_post.email}, function (err, doc){
  // doc is a Document
   if (err) { return next(err); }
   if (!doc) { return next(new Error('can\'t find')); }

    console.log(doc); // log the post in console
    res.json(doc);
});
 });
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I only want to get one data record, identified by the email address. Than this record should be the value of the form field. This way the user can see, he already posted a project and he´s able to update it in the form field.

Comment: @DavidNnamremmiz Try above code, I have used same code to search through posts in my mongodb.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, problem: I want to do the query, every time a user is on its profile page, and not only when he POSTs something. So if I get it right, i have to pass the mail address in an angular controller to the GET route, so mongo gives me the expected data.